# Assigning math.random value to array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a quick question I am testing out the Math.random functionality.  I am trying to assign the result from the `(int) (Math.random()*6)+1` for each one of the 100 boxes to an array to store the values.  But I am getting an error that it is not a statement.  Can someone possibly offer some guidance?

```
public shoes(int[] pairs)
{
   System.out.println("We will roll go through the boxes 100 times and store the input for the variables");
   for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
   {
       //("Random Number ["+ (i+1) + "] : " + (int)(Math.random()*6));
       int boxCount[i]  =  (int) (Math.random()*6) + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Math.random()`... it doesn't suit your purpose and is difficult to read. Use `Random rand = new Random();` and `rand.nextInt(6)+1;` instead.

Comment: Why are you declearing int boxCount[i] = ... like this, it doesnt' make sense.

Comment: Your method has no return type.

Comment: @AlexLockwood - per the docs, Math.random() instantiates a new `java.util.Random` on the first call and returns the equivalent of `Random.nextDouble()`. I agree is is odd though.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, that's why it would make more sense to use `java.util.Random` directly... using `Math.random()` just makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error. `boxCount` has not been instantiated and is not a known type. You need to create the `boxCount` array before you attempt to use it. See example below:

```
public void shoes(int[] pairs)
{
    System.out.println("We will roll go through the boxes 100 times and store the input for the variables");
    int boxCount[] = new int[100];
    for(int i=0; i < boxCount.length; i++)
    {
        //("Random Number ["+ (i+1) + "] : " + (int)(Math.random()*6));
        boxCount[i]  =  (int) (Math.random()*6) + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int boxCount[i]  =  (int) (Math.random()*6) + 1;
```

This line of code looks like you are trying to create an array or something.

You want to create the array `boxCount` BEFORE your for loop:

```
int boxCount[] = new int[100];
```

Then you can do this in your loop:

```
boxCount[i]  =  (int) (Math.random()*6) + 1;
```